# Is there a good set of lectures or notes on topology for studying characteristic classes?

Tags: reference-request, characteristic-classes, morse-theory

I was watching the lectures of Dr. Tadashi Tokieda on ["topology and geometry"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXHHvoaSctc&list=PLTBqohhFNBE_09L0i-lf3fYXF5woAbrzJ), which was pretty amazing that I finished all the the lectures in 3 days. What particularly helpful was the pictures he drew on the black board. Whenever he describe a homeomorphism, he drew pictures of intermediate stages of the deformation, that helped me a lot.

Towards the end of the [lecture 13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3L67ZyUJbU&list=PLTBqohhFNBE_09L0i-lf3fYXF5woAbrzJ&index=30) he talked about twistedness of a manifold and how "characteristic classes" can be used to measure how twisted a manifold is. That was exactly what I am looking for quite some time on youtube but failed to get a good video to learn about. But to my unlucky, that was only a mention of "characteristic classes". He just continued on some other topic in the later lectures.

Are there any set of lectures or a good reference on "characteristic classes"?

I am desparately looking for a good set of lectures on characteristic classes. Although Prof. Tadashi set a high standard of a lecture in topology, it would be great even if it is not that pictorial.

Comment: The standard reference is Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*.

Comment: Also, as an aside, watching all the lectures from a three week course in three days is way too fast if this is your first exposure to the subject.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I don't have a clue on how fast others learn, but if prof. Tadashi has more courses like that, I am pretty sure that I will learn things much easier. Unfortunately there were no other courses by him apart from some general talks.  Thanks to that great man!